# Does $R_q(x,y)\to0 \text{ as } q\to\infty$ for some open set containing $(1,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{\cos y}{x},y>0$. Does $R_q(x,y)\to0  \ \text{as} q\to\infty$ for some open set containing $(1,0)$.  $R_q$ is the remainder in Taylor's formulas

What i know is that $R_q(x_0+dx)={1\over q!}\sum_{i_1,...,i_q}^{n}f_{i_1}..._{i_q}(x_0+s(dx))\cdot dx^{i_1}...dx^{i_q},\text{for some} s\in (0,1)$ and i need to find an upper bound for $\sum_{i_1,...,i_q}^{n}f_{i_1}..._{i_q}(x_0+s(dx))\cdot dx^{i_1}...dx^{i_q}$. How to bound this stuff or is there any other approaches? Any hints?